# Disable google sheet download from everyone except owner

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

How can I disable the download from all the editors of the sheet. The data is confidential and I don't want employees (who are editors) to download the sheet.

I have enabled the following as well

- Prevent editors from changing access and adding new people
- Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers
- I Have put protected sheets only accessible to owner of the sheet and disable for all the other editors

However, the editors can still download the google sheet (csv and other formats)

Is there a way we can restrict any downloads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did correct:

[image]

But If your employees want to download your data, they will do it, here are few basic ways:

- Make screenshots and send to personal emails or store on pendrive
- Make photos with phones, drones, telescopes
- Write on paper, sole boot
- Memorize..

Comment: the above are fine for me. i just don't want the download function. currently the employees can download

Comment: Do the employees need to see ALL of the confidential data in the sheet, or are they only adding new records/data to the existing sheet?  Or else could the fields/columns they need to edit be kept separate, and a master sheet pulls all the data together that only you can edit?